# Combining a dataset of monthly observations with a dataset of annual observations for regression analysis

Tags: regression, data

So i'm collecting datasets from various databases, and some of these are annual (going back 5 years), and som are monthly (same number of years). It basically says 2022, 2021, 2020, etc, for one. The other goes january, february, mars, etc. for these years. So the question is how do i transform the datasets to make them comparable and be used for regression analysis. The picture illustrates the challenge. Variable 1 changes annually while variable 2 changes monthly.

[image: variable 1 varies annually, variable 2 varies monthly]

To my knowledge i have 2 choices to make them comparable and run a regression:

1. I could sum up the monthly variable for each of the years, basically summing up the 12 months for 1 year 5 times.
2. I could take the monthly average for the annual variable to make it an equal number of observations to the monthly. I would be doing this because i dont have monthly observations for the annual variable. The downside is that there isn't much variations monthly because i'm taking the average, and the whole point with a regression is to explain the variation in Y by the variation in Y.

Number 2 can make sense for figures such as annual income where salary contracts are fixed for a year and the monthly salary is the same. So if you had salaries for many years then you would at least capture some variation across the years. But it makes sense that this type of salary doesn't vary much.

Comment: Hi! 1. There does not seem to be a question? 2. The aggregation should depend on the type of data, e.g.: summing up monthly average temperatures (or averaging monthly temperature highs) does seem rather meaningless. Therefore sharing the type of your data is probably relevant to whatever the question will end up being,

Comment: Also important: what type of analysis do you want to conduct? The answer may depend on it.